# JSON data appears in console but is coming up as `undefined` in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, methods, append

I have some JSON data where some elements share values, so I reduced that data into new JSON where the values are correctly nested:

```
 (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
   0:
    SameGroup: Array(3)
     0: {Role: "SomeRole", IsFilled: false, isActive: true}
     1: {Role: "AnotherRole", IsFilled: true, isActive: false}
     2: {Role: "OtherRole", IsFilled: false, isActive: true}
     length: 3
     Title: "Title-A"
   1: {Title: "Title-B", SameGroup: Array(2)}
```

I'm trying to append that new JSON into unique divs (which I had working earlier), by replacing the data source that's filtered. In the console I can see the JSON tree but in the browser it's coming up as `undefined.`

I think there's a problem with implementing the new JSON into my old code (a problem with how it's filtered). Any thoughts on this one?

#### JS snippet:

```
function _displayForm() {
    let titleKeyHolder = [];
    let titleArr = [];

    jsonData.d.results.forEach(function(item) {
        titleKeyHolder[item.Title] = titleKeyHolder[item.Title] || {};
        let obj = titleKeyHolder[item.Title];
        if(Object.keys(obj).length == 0)
            titleArr.push(obj);

        obj.Title = item.Title;
        obj.SameGroup = obj.SameGroup || [];

        obj.SameGroup.push({ Role:item.Role, IsFilled: item.IsFilled, isActive: item.IsActive });
    });

    console.log(titleArr);

    let jobTitle = titleArr // ------ based on the JSON shape, I'm guessing I can't have titleArr written like this
        .filter(x => x.Title !== "");

        jobTitle.forEach(val => {
            let $clonedDiv = $("#template").clone();
            $clonedDiv.removeAttr("id");

            $clonedDiv
               .find("#display-form-job-title")
               .append(val.Title);

        // other code
}

_displayForm();
```

#### Old JSON: https://jsfiddle.net/vrep307f/

Comment: Fiddle link goes to a blank fiddle

Comment: @charlietfl Just updated it

Comment: So where specifically is it undefined? Sounds like an asynchronous ajax issue. Would help if you remove the irrelevant code. We don't need to see every element you create

Comment: In my browser I'm getting `undefined` in each div, where the data's supposed to be.

Comment: Now you removed too much. We can't tell where you use the array now in order to see what is undefined

Comment: Sorry about that. I just brought some of it back

Comment: Create a runnable demo that reproduces problem

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you have a problem when converting the data received, try to take inspiration from this code

```html
<script>

var text = '{"d":{"employees":[' +
'{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" },' +
'{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" },' +
'{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }]}}';




var obj = JSON.parse(text);


obj.d.employees.forEach(function(item) {

console.log(item.firstName);
})


</script>
```